# How to make CircuitTikZ symbols smaller

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, dimensions

Is there a way to make symbols of the CircuitTikz package smaller (like ports). Using small/tiny as argument doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've founded myself, using the scale attribute:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,2) node[and port,scale=0.5] (myand1) {};
\end{circuitikz}
```